# Category Search functionality on category metabox (wordpress admin)

Tags: categories, metabox, search

I have lots of categories on my blog site. When I add new post and select category, I need to scroll down to find the category. Is it possible to add a search category functionality in category metabox? [Click here](http://s13.postimg.org/m6uahjuo7/search_category.jpg) to view the image of the functionality that I want.

I would appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: it's not possible to modify the post categories meta box.

Comment: @MortalViews of course it is possible

Answer (score 5):

There is a plugin for that [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-category-search/), but I have issues with it. I use it to search for product categories, of which I have over 6,200. I would guesstimate that it fails to find the category(ies) I'm searching for about 30% of the time.  Also, it isn't verified to be completely successful with the current WordPress version.

A better alternative for you might be to use one of the taxonomy filter plugins. They filter the category list as you type. The one I'm currently using, and having success with, is [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-category-filter/screenshots/).

Good luck to you in finding what you're looking for.